Ground truth : active learning not triggered
I would like to test active learning.
To do so, I have created a dataset of 200 images AND I set MaxConcurrentTaskCount to 50.
I expect active learning to start after : 50 + 0.2 * 200 = 90 images labeled by human (as specified in this thread)
But nothing happens. Here is a subset of my labeling job description (after having 100 images labeled by human):
 'LabelingJobStatus': 'InProgress',
 'LabelCounters': {'TotalLabeled': 100,
  'HumanLabeled': 100,
  'MachineLabeled': 0,
  'FailedNonRetryableError': 0,
  'Unlabeled': 100},
 'LabelAttributeName': 'category',
 'LabelingJobAlgorithmsConfig': {'LabelingJobAlgorithmSpecificationArn': 'arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-west-2:027400017018:labeling-job-algorithm-specification/object-detection',
  'LabelingJobResourceConfig': {}},
  'MaxConcurrentTaskCount': 50,

What's wrong with this ?
I expect active learning to start after 90 images

You are right that the validation set is 90 images for a dataset size of 200 images. However, after labeling these 90 images, additional human-labeled data is required to train the model sufficiently before automated labeling can commence. Given the relatively small size of your dataset, the model may need more human-labeled examples to achieve the confidence necessary to start the automated labeling process. Continuing to label more images manually should help in triggering the active learning phase.
The MaxConcurrentTaskCount of 50 impacts the labeling rate but may also lead to a lag in training and triggering active learning if Ground Truth is processing these in batches or waiting for confirmation of annotation completion across all tasks.
Please also refer to this blog post for more details:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/annotate-data-for-less-with-amazon-sagemaker-ground-truth-and-automated-data-labeling/
